# Glassfish not starting after changes made to http listener 1 in glassfish admin console

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-4

After changing the port number from 8080 to 8181 of the http listener and checking on the box to enable its security from the admin console, glassfish wouldn't start anymore and I can't access the admin consol anymore (to cancel the changes I did) because for that glassfish needs to be running.
I cannot afford to delete glassfish and reinstall it as I would lose all the configuration I already did for it.

Please provide a solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by going to GlassFish_Server/glassfish/domains/domain1/config and inside config I opened the domain.xml file.
In domain.xml I searched for http listener 1 and changed its port from 8181 to 8080 and then changed "security enabled" from true to false.